# Why does Armory rescan the block chain every time it opens?

Tags: armory

The title says it all: every time I open Armory, it appears to rescan the entire block chain (after synchronizing). Why can't it just keep a file that says if any blocks contain transactions for my wallets, or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just release version 0.90-beta, which finally solves this issue.  Armory does **not** need to rescan the blockchain anymore unless you import new private keys, or Armory experiences an unclean shutdown.

With the exception of the first-time startup (to build the new databases), Armory should get into online mode within 10 seconds of Bitcoin-Qt/bitcoind finishing synchronization.

Comment: hm, I'm using 0.90 and it's still scanning the whole transaction history :/

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical limitation, the developer just hasn't gotten around to it yet. This is part of a larger rework of the Armory block chain database.

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory/issues/93) for more.